# is it possible to export 10g database schema from 11g server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, schema, datapump

I want to export 10g database schema and import the files into 11g database. Here are my constraints:

I have little space in 10g database server to export the dump file for schemas.

I tried to export using 11g client installed on my Windows 7 workstation. I get version incompatible error using expdp command. I also doubt datapump utility is permitted only at server  level.

Please advice.

Comment: What kind of privileges do you have on both systems? The short answer to your question is "YES". It is possible to export a 10G database and import that into a 11G server.

Comment: Since there is so little space available, I don't suppose anyone would know if it would be possible to use a named pipe as the dump file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a database link in the 11 database to the 10 schema.
Start expdp on the 11 database using the NETWORK_LINK parameter. 
The NETWORK_LINK parameter identifies a database link to be used as the source for a network export/import.

See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php#NetworkExportsImports for detailed instructions

Comment: Thank you for the response on this issue. I got server access to take the dumps.